# python function parameter:complex parameter structure understanding

Tags: python-3.x

```
 def resize_img( size: Tuple[int, int] = (299, 299)):
     pass
```

## What does the parameter mean？I did not find the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are asking about `Tuple[int, int]`: this syntax is provided by [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module. It helps you and other people reading your code to understand which type should parameters have when passed into function. In your example - if you try to pass something different than tuple of two ints (i.e. `resize_img(5)`) IDE will mark it as `Expected type 'Tuple[int]', got 'int' instead`. This **does not** break code execution, but shows developer that probably he/she uses this function with wrong type of parameter passed in.